# Two different actions for a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I handle different interactions with a link? For example, when a user clicks the page opens another link, and when the user leaves the mouse pressed for more than 2 seconds opens another link?

Comment: Read about `JS mouse events`

Comment: $('#element').hover(function()
{
    $(this).data('timeout', window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        functionOne();
    }, 2000));
},
function()
{
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    functionTwo();
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a simple handler prototype for this:

```js
function LinkMouseHandler(linkElement, ref) {
  this.mouseDownTimeStamp = 0;
  linkElement.onmousedown = function(e) {
    this.mouseDownTimeStamp = e.timeStamp;
  }
  linkElement.onmouseup = function(e) {
    if (e.timeStamp - this.mouseDownTimeStamp < 2000)
      window.location.href = ref;
    else
      alert("test");
  }
}

var mouseHandler = new LinkMouseHandler(document.getElementById("test"), "http://www.google.de");
```

```html
<a id="test">bla</a>
```

Comment: thank you friend, you saved my life, I was not able to have this logic.